# Data command does not refresh Tererik report

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have an MVC project with a razor page that has 5 separate tabs. The telerik report is on the 5th tab so it does not load when the page loads. If the report is on the first tab then it will load when the page initially loads. We were previously using telerik reporting 2016 R3 and using the command `$("[data-command='telerik_ReportViewer_refresh']").first().click();` on the first tab in the script section to refresh the report without issues. When recently upgraded to 2020 R1 and now that command doesn't seem to work. I can't seem to find any documentation changes regarding the data-commands. The [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/html5-report-viewer-data-attributes) has stayed the same. Is this command correct now?

I've tried using the command

```
var reportViewer = $("#trvReportViewerSIDLabels").data("telerik_ReportViewer");
reportViewer.refreshReport();
```

and it just gives me an `undefined` error on reportViewer. I'm positive the report name element is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not load all tab content at the same time. Only on the active tab that is selected. I had to attach a listener to the tab that had the report and have it execute the refresh command after the tab is shown.

```
<script>
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
            $('*[data-command="telerik_ReportViewer_refresh"]').first().click();
        });
</script>
```